# jQuery function BEFORE form submission

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit

I am trying to fire a function using Jquery when the form submit button is clicked, but the function needs to fire BEFORE the form is actually submitted.

I am trying to copy some `div` tag attributes into hidden text fields upon submission, and then submit the form.

I have managed to get this to work using the `mouseover` function (when the submit button is hovered over), but this will not work on mobile devices using touch.

```
$("#create-card-process.design #submit").on("mouseover", function () {
    var textStyleCSS = $("#cover-text").attr('style');
    var textbackgroundCSS = $("#cover-text-wrapper").attr('style');
    $("#cover_text_css").val(textStyleCSS);
    $("#cover_text_background_css").val(textbackgroundCSS);
});
```

I have played around with the `submit` function, but the values are not saved within the fields as the function fires when the form is submitted and not before.

Many thanks.

Comment: The `submit` event (on the form) should run when you click the submit button, and it will run before the form is submitted natively.  You can also try using a `click` event on the submit button itself.

Comment: What problems do you have with the `submit` function, I don't understand your last sentence.  What does "values are not saved within the fields" mean?  Do you have any other JavaScript (validation maybe) on the form?

Comment: Can you give us a fiddle? If you want to ensure an animation is run before submit, using `timeout` is also an option.

Comment: You can get the values from the fields using `.val()` function. The values should be there.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can use the onsubmit function.

If you return false the form won't get submitted. Read up about it [here](https://api.jquery.com/submit/).

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
  // your code here
});
```

Comment: The question is how to add code before the submit. This answer explains how to prevent the submit, which are two different things.

Answer (score 92):

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
  // your code here
})
```

The above is **NOT** working in **Firefox**. The form will just simply submit without running your code first. Also, similar issues are mentioned elsewhere... such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548801/form-submitfunction-not-working-in-firefox).
The workaround will be

```
$('#myform').submit(function(event) {

 event.preventDefault(); //this will prevent the default submit

  // your code here (But not asynchronous code such as Ajax because it does not wait for a response and move to the next line.)
  
 $(this).unbind('submit').submit(); // continue the submit unbind preventDefault
})
```

Comment: Is it still the case with Firefox? This answer was given 5 years ago.

Comment: I just installed Firefox to test it. I'm on version 87. The simple `submit` is doing it just fine, no need to `preventDefault`. I'm on jquery 3.5.1.

Comment: Is the code inside the submit callback function works? before the form submits? without using return false as mentioned in the accepted answer?

Comment: The submit() is actually used to submit form, so if you wish to run your code before submit then you need to preventDefault When using only `return false` there is no way for you to continue submit form after your function runs ... but with combination of `preventDefault` and `unbind` you can continue with submit after running your function.  https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Is the code inside the submit callback function works? - Yes.
before the form submits? - Yes. 
If you return false the form won't get submitted? - Yes.

Comment: When using only `return false` there is no way for you to continue submit form... - yes it was the point. If you return false the form won't get submitted.

Comment: combination ... blah - blah - blah... If you want the form submitted then don't `return false`. It is very simple.

Answer (score 4):

Based on Wakas Bukhary answer, you could make it async by puting the last line in the response scope.

```
$('#myform').submit(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault(); //this will prevent the default submit
  var _this = $(this); //store form so it can be accessed later

  $.ajax('GET', 'url').then(function(resp) {

    // your code here 

   _this.unbind('submit').submit(); // continue the submit unbind preventDefault
  })  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to give a modern Oct, 2021 answer.  Currently, `$('form').on('submit', function(event) {...})` will never execute before the actual submission in a number of certain cases: [FireFox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40330287/2430549) and [using HTML5 required on hidden inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22148080/2430549).

I have tested the following solution in Chrome, Firefox, and Brave.  Simply set the `onClick()` of the submit button as your eventhandler.  You can cancel the submission by `event.preventDefault();` if you don't want the submit to happen.  In addition, selecting a text or checkbox input, and hitting enter, *still* calls the `onClick` event, even though no-onClick happened, because the browser understands it as a shortcut for clicking your `<input type="submit">`.

```js
var allowSubmit = false;
document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if(allowSubmit) {
        console.log("Submit allowed.");
        return true;
    }
    
    console.log("Submit prevented.");
    
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Button">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like the following  these days by referencing the "beforeSubmit" jquery form event. I'm disabling and enabling the submit button to avoid duplicate requests, submitting via ajax, returning a message that's a json array and displaying the information in a pNotify:

```
jQuery('body').on('beforeSubmit', "#formID", function() {
    $('.submitter').prop('disabled', true);
    var form = $('#formID');
    $.ajax({
        url    : form.attr('action'),
        type   : 'post',
        data   : form.serialize(),
        success: function (response)
        {
            response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            new PNotify({
                text: response.message,
                type: response.status,
                styling: 'bootstrap3',
                delay: 2000,
            });
            $('.submitter').prop('disabled', false);
        },
        error  : function ()
        {
            console.log('internal server error');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I cannot find any documentation for a jQuery beforeSubmit event.

Comment: I've found this in case it helps in any way https://jquery-form.github.io/form/options/

Comment: Ah OK it is a plugin, that makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Aghhh... i was missing some code when i first tried the .submit function.....

This works:

```
$('#create-card-process.design').submit(function() {
    var textStyleCSS = $("#cover-text").attr('style');
    var textbackgroundCSS = $("#cover-text-wrapper").attr('style');
    $("#cover_text_css").val(textStyleCSS);
    $("#cover_text_background_css").val(textbackgroundCSS);
});
```

Thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some div or span instead of button and then on click call some function which submits form at he end.

```
<form id="my_form">
   <span onclick="submit()">submit</span>
</form>

<script>
   function submit()
   {   
       //do something
       $("#my_form").submit();
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Carefull, this will fail when a user hits [Enter] on one of the fields

Comment: It will not fail. It simply won't be called ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just because I made this mistake every time when using the submit function.

This is the full code you need:

Add the id "**yourid**" to the HTML form tag.

```
<form id="yourid" action='XXX' name='form' method='POST' accept-charset='UTF-8' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

the jQuery code:

```
$('#yourid').submit(function() {
  // do something
});
```